# Sequelize: How to subquery a through table

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Maybe I'm expecting too much magic out of Sequelize, but I'm wondering if there's a way to query a through table without using two separate queries. Here's my code, where `Role` is the through table and `activeTeam` is set on the user.

```js
    let user = await User.findOne({ 
      where: { email }
    })

    let role = await Role.findOne({
      where: {
        userId: user.id,
        teamId: user.activeTeam.id
      }
    })
```

Is there a way to avoid two separate queries here? Can I lazy load the role somehow like this?

```js
    let user = await User.findOne({ 
      where: { email },
      include: [ Team ]
    })

    // Now, get the specific role I need
    user.getRoles(/* can you put a where clause in here or something? */)
```

Comment: That is where you wish you could just write simple SQL query. Personally I suggest to use QueryBuilder, take a look at `sql-bricks`

Comment: @karianpour, I'm comfortable writing it as a SQL query, but trying to avoid to keep the code clean. My solution in the meantime has been to query the through table first, since in most cases I have the `user.id` and `team.id` available, and then include the `User` and `Team` models.

Comment: in my point of view, using query build make you code much more cleaner and declarative, beside you have all the power of the SQL and the underlying database. Give it a try ;)